# Point-wise convergence of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converges pointwise to

$0$, if $0≤x<1$.
$\frac{1}{2}$, if $x=1$.
$1$, if $x>1$

Which is seen by checking the conditions first for $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n$ and then for $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{1+x_n}$.

I'd like to understand how the case for $x>1$ is seen.

Comment: Why do you think the sum is $0$ if $0 < x < 1$? The sum of positive series is positive.

Comment: Do you mean the sum, or just the terms in the sum?

Comment: These statements are true for the $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}}$ but not for the $\sum_{n =0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: $$\frac{1}{x^n}>\frac{1}{x^n+1}>0$$

so:

$$1-\frac{1}{x^n}<1-\frac{1}{x^n+1}=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}<1$$

So if $x>1$ then $\frac{1}{x^n}\to 0$, and apply the squeeze theorem.